# Как убрать скобки '[]' при сохранении списка в файл?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, csv

Задача такая: 
У меня есть массив значений. 
Вот пример:

```
[[1.01, 2.01, 1.5729039803815916],
 [1.01, 2.0199999999999996, 1.5729039803815916],
 [1.01, 2.0299999999999994, 1.5729039803815916],
 [1.01, 2.039999999999999, 1.5729039803815916],
 [1.01, 2.049999999999999, 1.5729039803815916],
 [1.01, 2.0599999999999987, 1.5729039803815916]]
```

Эти значения я хочу сохранить в csv файл. Делаю это вот так:

```
with open('lot_lang_distance.csv', 'w') as file:
    for i in s:
        k = str(i)
        file.write(f'{k}\n')
```

Результат в файле:

```
[1.01, 2.01, 1.5729039803815916]
[1.01, 2.0199999999999996, 1.5729039803815916]
[1.01, 2.0299999999999994, 1.5729039803815916]
[1.01, 2.039999999999999, 1.5729039803815916]
[1.01, 2.049999999999999, 1.5729039803815916]
[1.01, 2.0599999999999987, 1.5729039803815916]
```

Я хочу получить вот такой результат:

```
1.01, 2.01, 1.5729039803815916,
1.01, 2.0199999999999996, 1.5729039803815916
1.01, 2.0299999999999994, 1.5729039803815916
1.01, 2.039999999999999, 1.5729039803815916
1.01, 2.049999999999999, 1.5729039803815916
1.01, 2.0599999999999987, 1.5729039803815916
```

Т. е. я хочу убрать скобки (должна быть структура обычного csv файла). Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь модулем Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(lst).to_csv(r"c:\temp\lot_lang_distance.csv", header=None, index=False)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
with open('lot_lang_distance.csv', 'w') as file:
    file.write('\n'.join(', '.join(str(j) for j in i) for i in s))
```

Comment: Ваш код выдает вот такой результат: https://prnt.sc/rj3eq8

Comment: @ivan100096 А у вас в массиве не строки уже случайно со скобками прямо внутри? попробуйте напечатать type(s) и type(i) и узнать, что у вас там вообще.

Comment: У меня <class 'list'>  для type(s) и type(i)